# I can not use min and max with having in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to find the job with the smaller number of emplyers but I can't use the min function on the having clause.

```
SELECT JOB, COUNT(*) AS "NUMBER OF EMPLOYEES"
FROM EMP
GROUP BY JOB
HAVING COUNT(*) = MIN(COUNT(*))
ORDER BY JOB
```

Comment: Looks like you will lneed to do some reseach on how to do it in Oracle then. How much [research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: What would `min(count(*))` be? A `job` can only have one count.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FETCH` clause like this

```
SELECT JOB, COUNT(*) AS "NUMBER OF EMPLOYEES"
FROM EMP
GROUP BY JOB
ORDER BY "NUMBER OF EMPLOYEES"
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
```

Ohh!! Its oracle 11g, then use following:

```
SELECT JOB, COUNT(*) AS "NUMBER OF EMPLOYEES"
FROM EMP
GROUP BY JOB
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT MIN(COUNT(*)
FROM EMP GROUP BY JOB)
ORDER BY JOB
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

You want to count employees per job. You want then to show the job(s) with the least number of employees. That is two steps.

One way:

```
select job, employees
from
(
  select job, count(*) as employees, min(count(*)) over () as min_employees
  from emp
  group by job
)
where employees = min_employees;
```

Another:

```
with jobs as (select job, count(*) as employees from emp group by job)
select *
from jobs
where employees = (select min(employees) from jobs);
```